# Will buying Origin keys from third-party resellers go though Origin age restrictions?

Tags: battlefield-4, origin, battlefield-premium

I want to buy Battlefield 4 Premium while it is on sale, but because of me being a complete tool, I put my actual age in. I bought the digital deluxe version on disc, and I just want the premium upgrade instead of another copy just to get the premium from it.

**TL;DR**: Will game keys work in Origin even if the account does not meet the game's age requirements?

Comment: I would guess that it has the same restrictions.

Comment: **Do NOT buy from G2A.** That site is known to re-sell fraudulent keys, which can cause trouble. [Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Steam/comments/2yhnsw/key_resellers_and_what_they_mean_for_you/)'s a great reddit post about key resellers.

Comment: @MrLemon: G2A was edited out of his question, you might want to delete your comment to remove mention from the site [this comment will be deleted as well].

Answer (score 1):

No it will not. It does not matter where the Key comes from, you just can not do the download/play the game.